# Running GUI apps in Goland IDE

Tags: user-interface, go, goland

When I build in Terminal, I can use a flag to say I want to build for GUI:

```
go build -ldflags="-H windowsgui"
```

However, I just started using JetBrains Goland and I don't how to run GUI apps. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`go build` will only build the application.

To actually run the application, you should go to `Run | Edit Configurations... | + | Go Application` and configure the application as you need.

Here you will need to set two options:

- add `-ldflags="-H windowsgui"` to the `Go tool arguments` option
- configure the `Output directory` to be in the same directory as your `.manifest` file

Setting the output directory is critical in order to run the the application without encountering the following panic `panic: TTM_ADDTOOL failed` described [in this issue](https://github.com/lxn/walk/issues/28).

Then you can run the configuration via `Run | Run...` and select the configuration you've just created.

Comment: This is exactly what I just did. I just added `-ldflags="-H windowsgui"` to the `Go tool arguments`. But when I run it, no window appears.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of this, as I don't have any such application available to debug. Or raise an issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go

Comment: I could provide you the code but it requires a lib (walk).

Comment: I guess I have to stick to a simple text editor + terminal for now. It seems gogland is still buggy or missing some things (I can't even build and generate an exe file, I can only run and debug).

Comment: Just building an executable without running it is not currently supported, see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-2408 This is by design, not a bug. Buggy / missing some things, it cannot be improved if the information required to reproduce the issues is not provided. I have no way to test how this works on my machine, or doesn't if there's no minimal Hello World that breaks for you or at least some instructions on how to reproduce it. I'm sorry I don't have a better answer for you.

Comment: Here's the GUI lib I am using: https://github.com/lxn/walk. They also have an example (this is the one I test).

Comment: Thank you. Based on that information I've been able to replicate the problem and using this code: https://play.golang.org/p/FtP297tvAv I've been able to get the panic that was missing in order to provide the information needed to debug this problem. Turns out it's not an IDE problem but a missing configuration needed by Windows to allow the application to run. Point the Output Directory in the sample place as the ` .manifest ` file is and it will work. I've updated the answer as such.